# 'Scoring' regular expressions based on their ambiguity

Tags: regex, algorithm

I have a number of regular expressions provided by the user and select one of them which matches an input string. Now, in the event that multiple of the expressions match, I would like to select the one that is most specific, i.e. the least ambiguous.

**More specifically:** I'm writing an IRC bot with a couple of people, in Python to be precise. Commands can be registered by regex, where some of them overlap. It would be possible to provide some sort of priority with each command, however this would introduce another point of failure. I would prefer if a sort of 'score' could be generated automatically on command registration, based on how ambiguous the provided regex is. I haven't been able to find an appropriate algorithm on Google yet.

A naive approach, which may work for my needs for now, might be the ratio of characters to wildcards in the regex, however I'd be interested if you know of any concrete algorithms here.

Comment: I severely doubt such a thing exists since regex can be written in so many ways and using so many combinations of wildcards and groups that I believe specificity may be subjective, but hoping I'm wrong for your sake and good luck.

Comment: This is a pretty good question.  A lot of people on SO like to mark questions as "too broad" when they don't know the answer, it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use grep-style regular expressions that can be converted to a DFA, then for any regular expression, it it's possible to calculate the probability that a random string would match it.

I think this is a reasonable choice for the kind of score you're looking for -- the lower the probability of a match by a random string, the more specific the regex is.  For extra points your notion of a "random string" can model the sorts of strings that people actually type.

It's not easy, but it's doable. The process would work like this:

1. Generate a minmal DFA (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) for your the regular expression. Typically this is done using using Thompson's construction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction) to create an NFA, converting to a DFA using the powerset construction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction), and then applying Hopcroft's algorithm or similar (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization) to create a minimal DFA.
2. Add a single accepting state to the DFA to handle "end of string".  Add a transition on "end of string" from each previous accepting state to the the new single accepting state.
3. Now you need to calculate the probability that a random string will enter each state.  For the start state, this probability is 1.  For other states, you can make an equation that calculates the probability that it will be entered.  It is a sum of the probabilities for entering each preceding state, times the (constant) probability that the next transition from there would be to the target state. You may weight the transition probabilities according to the frequency that each letter actually appears in typed commands.  You will probably assume a constant probability that the string will end at each state (either transitioning to the accepting state or not)
4. In step (3) you cannot calculate the probabilities directly, but you can make  N linear equations for N unknowns, where the unknowns are the state entering probabilities for all states except the start state.  Use Gaussian elimination (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) or other standard method for solving systems of linear equations to calculate the probability that each state would be entered by a random string.

Step (4) will assign a probability for a random string entering the accepting state, which is the probability that a random string would match the regular expression.  The lower this probability is, the more specific the regular expression is.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth comment despite the question being put on hold. This might well go beyond my knowledge of automata, but I will give it a shot in the near future.